# How to print out every other line to the monitor

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

Have this tiny script down below and want to print out to the screen every other result. What are the ways of doing it?

```
#!/bin/bash

for ((n=5, j=1; j<=9;j++))
do
echo "rez: $n*$j"=$((n*j))

done
```

Comment: Do you mean something like `for ((n=5, j=1; j<=9;j+=2))`?

Comment: What monitor? What does it have to do with `printf`?

Comment: Sorry I did not put myself clear. The results comes out as a column on the screen as follows: rez:5*1=5 rez:5*2=10 rez:5*3=15 and so on. I need to display every other line. e.g rez:5*1=5 then empty line rez:5*3=15 empty line and so on.

Answer (score 4):

You could use `sed` to filter the output (of any command/script) and print every other line and double space the final output:
print only odd-numbered lines:

```
command | sed n\;g
```

print only even-numbered lines:

```
command | sed g\;n
```

*command* can be `for ... done`

Answer (score 1):

```
#! /bin/bash

for ((n=5, j=1; j<=9;j++)); do
    if [ $((j%2)) -eq 1 ]; then
        echo "rez: $n*$j"=$((n*j))
    else
        echo
    fi
done

rez: 5*1=5

rez: 5*3=15

rez: 5*5=25

rez: 5*7=35

rez: 5*9=45
```